# Return object handle from a subroutine

Tags: perl, oop, subroutine

I want to know if it is possible to return a object handle from a subroutine in a Perl program.
I will use a specific example from a program that uses [`MAIL::IMAPClient`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::IMAPClient)

Create client object handle

```
my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
   Socket   => $socket,
   User     => $user,
   Password => $pass,
  )
  or die "new(): $@";
```

I would like to create this object handle from a sub routine instead

```
my $client = &create_client_object;

sub create_client_object {

  my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
   Socket   => $socket,
   User     => $user,
   Password => $pass,
  )
  or die "new(): $@";

  return $client;
}
```

If possible, what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the Perl equivalent of a Java static factory method.  One note, do not use `&` when calling subroutines.  Instead use `my $client = create_client_object();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works perfectly. Besides @Miller's comment, I'd recommend you to also pass the `$socket`, `$user` and `$pass` as parameters to your function instead of using them from context:

```
my $client = create_client_object($socket, $user, $pass);

sub create_client_object {
  my ($socket, $user, $pass) = @_;

  my $client = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
   Socket   => $socket,
   User     => $user,
   Password => $pass,
  )
  or die "new(): $@";

  return $client;
}
```